# Angular ng-click with array.prototype.map

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, array.prototype.map

I am trying to use an array.map function in my ng-click expression:

```
addTracksToPlaylist(album.tracks.items.map(function(o){return o.id}));
```

but I am getting a syntax error `Token '{' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 47 of the expression`. I don't really know what to do about this, I'm trying not to put the function in the scope or outside of my markup.

Comment: That is because whenever you use expressions in angular it expects an `angular` expression which is a subset of javascript. otherwise script injection would be too easy. You'll have to settle for a function in your controller that returns the filtered array. You can create a `$filter` and use it instead.

Comment: @MuliYulzary Can you provide an example on how to use it with $filter?

Comment: Here's a snippet I made: https://plnkr.co/edit/MpqbmOXYrmmoWIirvr7q?p=preview

Comment: Thankskssssss this is what I needed